# Add constraint to allow only distinct duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure if this has been asked before but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I want to add a constraint to allow only distinct duplicates of two columns:

```
User       Fob
2          123
2          123
2          456 <<<< NOT ALLOWED
```

So the last row is not allowed because it's a new combination of distinct values between Users and Fobs.

Comment: Seems like you should have 2 different tables and a relationship and `User` and `Fob` are `UNIQUE` in their respective tables; then a `User` can only be related to 1 `Fob`

Comment: This does indicate a normalisation problem / design issue but if you really need it you can use an indexed view grouping on `User, Fob` and with the unique index on the view just on `User` column

Comment: Yea I had considered that, I think I'll have a rethink of the relations and redesign the tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can count each combination and get only those having more than 1.

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=06b12096b457b1e00813ae25a22c4cdc):

```
SELECT
  User,
  Fob,
  count(*) as lines
FROM example_table
GROUP BY User, Fob
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```